# Excel get cell value from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Good morning all,

I'm looking for possible alternatives to my current system of importing data from multiple "unit" workbooks into a "master" workbook. Each of my "unit" workbooks is built from a fixed template, so their sheet names and cell references are always the same. (Sheet names are: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, ... Dec)(File names are: YYYY_Location_Description)

Ideally I would like to be able to simply do a sumproduct through all open workbook files. I know I can do it through sheets using Jan:Dec!A2:D5. But is there a way to adapt this to run through all open workbook files?

Currently I have a macro that systematically runs through all files listed by DIR and copies the data out of the "unit" sheets one entry at a time and pastes it in a summary sheet.

Each monthly "unit" sheet consists of a row for each day of the month and columns as shown:

```
UnitA
Date   HrsA    HrsB    ValueA    ValueB    ValueC  ...
1      24      0       0.01      0.02      0.01
2      0       24      0.01      0.015     0.012
...
```

The macro copied data is then placed in the format:

```
Master
Date   Location    Value    HrsA    HrsB    Entry
1      UnitA       ValueA   24      0       0.01
1      UnitA       ValueB   24      0       0.02
1      UnitA       ValueC   24      0       0.01
1      UnitA       ValueA   0       24      0.01
1      UnitA       ValueB   0       24      0.015
1      UnitA       ValueC   0       24      0.012
```

Which is a lot of data in the "master" summary sheet. What I'd rather be able to do is:

```
=sum('[Workbook1.xls:WorkbookN.xls]Jan:Dec'!$A$2:$D$5)
```

Is it possible to do anything like this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, just loop over each of the open workbooks and evaluate the `Sum` of the specified range, and then write that value to ActiveCell (or wherever it needs to be placed)

```
Sub foo()
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ret

For Each wb in Application.Workbooks
    '[Workbook1.xls:WorkbookN.xls]Jan:Dec'!$A$2:$D$5)
    ret = ret + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( _
                    "'[" & wb.Name & "]Jan:Dec'!$A$2:$D$5")
Next

ActiveCell.Value = ret
End Function
```

Or try this to build the formula string:

```
Sub foo(Optional sheetRange As String = "Jan:Dec", Optional cellsRange As String = "A2:D5")
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ret

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    ret = ret & "SUM('[" & wb.Name & "]" & sheetRange & "'!" & cellsRange & ")+"
Next
ret = Left(ret, Len(ret) - 1)
ret = "=" & ret
ActiveCell.Formula = ret
End Sub
```

Comment: My hope was to not involve any VBA if possible. Though using your suggestion I could pre-evaluate the data into the level of granularity I need for each report. Ideally if I could just do it as a formula reference through all open workbooks...

Comment: If you're already using a macro, why not just extend it to do the sum?  You could adapt the VBA above to build the formula string (see above).